# NameError: global name 'Pubnub' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, pubnub

Im Deploying an Application Server on Bluemix using cf push, im receiving a error of "NameError: global name 'Pubnub' is not defined" but actually the first error i encountered is  "ERR ImportError: cannot import name Pubnub" then i got a solution looking in other threads where they suggest to change the syntax to "from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub" because i have PubNub v4 installed. Any Idea how to solve this. thanks. below is my code where the error is coming

```
def init():
    #Pubnub Initialization
    global pubnub 
    pubnub = Pubnub(publish_key=PUB_KEY,subscribe_key=SUB_KEY)
    pubnub.subscribe(channels='kitchenDevice-resp', callback=callback, error=callback, reconnect=reconnect, disconnect=disconnect)
    pubnub.subscribe(channels='kitchenApp-req', callback=appcallback, error=appcallback, reconnect=reconnect, disconnect=disconnect)
```

Comment: `pubnub` *is not defined* then.

Comment: If you get an import error then the package is not installed in a place where the Python you are running can find it.

Comment: i am newbie on Python programmming, how can i know what package is not installed? and how can i defined pubnub? thanks

Comment: Did you use `pip` to install Python and other Python modules? If so, in terminal, type `pip list`. For PubNub SDK, see https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk#how_to_get_it

Comment: See Adam's answer below. It should provide everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting which is deprecated/EOL'ed, although, it should work.

Please be sure that you are using [PubNub Python SDK v4](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk) as v3 is no longer supported, although, it will still work.

If you provide more of your code (with the imports) that would be helpful but I would strongly suggest trying again with the v4 SDK and you can contact PubNub Support, if necessary.

Comment: the problem is the syntax that i want to test is for the v3 SDK.  this is the link of the project i want to test http://radiostud.io/iot-application-kitchen-inventory-management/

Comment: all the steps on that project is accomplished, the only i get stuck into is on the deployment of the server. can you help me out how can i fixed this? thanks

Comment: to be specific this is the link on the deployment: https://github.com/shyampurk/kitchen-tracker/blob/master/Deploy.md

Comment: thanks for the response anyway, wish you can help me out since i think you are PubNub support staff.

Comment: and this is the link to the code itself: https://github.com/shyampurk/kitchen-tracker/blob/master/kitchen_tracker/server.py

Answer (score 0):

Pip is the Python package manager. You use it to install packages and SDKs on your machine to run better Python apps.

To install with **Mac OS**, use this command in your terminal:

```
easy_install pip
```

[Installing Pip on Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/install-pip-in-linux/)

[Installing Pip on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379)

Use pip to install the PubNub Python v4 SDK (which is latest). Terminal command:

```
pip install 'pubnub>=4.1.2'
```

Here is the code to connect to PubNub and Publish and Subscribe to an awesome channel. Make sure that you put in your own [Free PubNub API keys](https://dashboard.pubnub.com/?devrel_gh=54056643) into the code:

```py
from pubnub.callbacks import SubscribeCallback
from pubnub.enums import PNStatusCategory
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub

pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)

def my_publish_callback(envelope, status):
    # Check whether request successfully completed or not
    if not status.is_error():
        print 'publish success'

class MySubscribeCallback(SubscribeCallback):
    def presence(self, pubnub, presence):
        pass
    def status(self, pubnub, status):
        pass
    def message(self, pubnub, message):
        print message.message

pubnub.add_listener(MySubscribeCallback())
pubnub.subscribe().channels("awesomeChannel").execute()

## publish a message
pubnub.publish().channel("awesomeChannel").message("publish from device").pn_async(my_publish_callback)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but the problem is the syntax that on the project i want to test is for v3, and i think that migrating the code to v4 will be a big problem to me. is there a way that i can still work on to the v3 code rather than the v4?

Comment: this is the link of the project that i am working on https://github.com/shyampurk/kitchen-tracker/blob/master/Deploy.md

Comment: Python v3 is no longer supported. The documentation is here https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk-v3

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to open a github issue in the repository. The author may respond with fixes. https://github.com/shyampurk/kitchen-tracker/issues

Comment: Thanks for the response. i already post the issue on the github.